# Does laravel 6 auto-load jquery? Getting uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I had this project working perfectly fine until I implemented authentication. I composer required laravel/ui then did php artisan ui vue --auth as per the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication)

Before the auth, the scripts were loading perfectly (this is a jquery table sorter plugin) and the functionality was a dream. After the auth scaffolding, it's giving me this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function`

Here is my code at the bottom of my view:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.tablesorter.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js')}}"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $("#myTable").tablesorter();
    });

    </script>
```

I don't work a lot with front end stuff and laravel 6 has a few features implemented that I'm sure I'm unaware of. Other SO articles say that this error is generally caused by loading jquery in more than one place. Does laravel implement jquery somewhere when doing the auth scaffolding? If not, what else could be giving me this error after implementing the auth? If I comment out the script line that has jquery as the "src", I get `jquery is not defined` and `$ is not defined`. So I don't know what's going on. Theoretically it's being double loaded but if i comment it out, it's obviously not loaded from somewhere else.

Comment: check the generated source or inspect the page and see what js files are being loaded

Comment: it's loading the correct files from my public folder. it has "jquery.tablesorter.js" and the widgets script

Comment: and check what else is being loaded

Comment: app.js from the auth scaffolding, a google font, and the standard bootstrap stuff. i even replaced jquery with a google hosted one instead of the slim one that bootstrap comes with on their "getting started" section

Comment: does bootstrap not use jquery? check these files and see including the app.js

Comment: bootstrap does use jquery but you have to include it ahead of their proprietary scripts. on their getting started section on the bootstrap 4 page, it's part of the scripts you copy/paste to your project

Comment: but even if those other scripts had jquery loaded, it shouldn't give me the "jquery undefined" and "$ undefined" errors if i comment it out, right?

Comment: as you said "Other SO articles say that this error is generally caused by loading jquery in more than one place" so you are now saying that isn't correct? they could be loading it differently

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this in the future, I believe that app.js generated by laravel authentication scaffolding includes jquery within itself. When I removed the jquery scripts from the bottom of the view and removed the "defer" parameter in the app.js script line at the top of app.blade, the code began to work again.

Comment: awesome, you found it :)